# Missing \begin{document} - LaTeX Error

Tags: errors, overleaf

I was making a template for Journal of Applied Crystallography, example available [here](https://www.iucr.org/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/27097/documentation.pdf) (please see Appendix D). Unfortunately, I am getting error mentioned in the title of the question. I followed this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138631/latex-error-missing-begin-document) to resolve the error with out any success. Below you can see a minimum working example. Here you can find [.cls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u8jl5xljtcuf9y/iucr.cls?dl=0) file

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Template file for the submission of papers to IUCr journals in LaTeX2e
% using the iucr document class
% Copyright 1999-2003 International Union of Crystallography
% Version 1.2 (11 December 2002)
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{iucr} % DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Information about the type of paper
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\paperprodcode{a000000} % Replace with production code if known
\paperref{xx9999} % Replace xx9999 with reference code if known
\papertype{FA} % Indicate type of article
% FA - research papers (full article)
% SC - short communications
% FC - fast communications
% LA - lead article
% TR - topical review
% XL - crystallization papers
% (Following categories rarely in LaTeX)
% AA - abstracts
% AD - addenda and errata
% AI - inorganic compounds
% AM - metal-organic compounds
% AO - organic compounds
% BC - books received
% BR - book reviews
% BI - biography
% CA - cif applications
% CD - crystal data
% CE - current events
% CI - inorganic compounds
% CL - calendar of events
% CM - metal-organic compounds
% CN - cryocrystallography papers
% CO - organic compounds
% CP - computer programs
% CR - crystallographers
% CS - scientific comment
% ED - editorial
% EI - inorganic compounds
% EM - metal-organic compounds
% EO - organic compounds
% FI - inorganic compounds
% FM - metal-organic compounds
% FO - organic compounds
% IP - issue preface
% IU - iucr
% LE - letters to the editor
% LN - laboratory notes
% ME - forthcoming meetings/short courses
% MR - meeting reports
% NN - notes and news
% NP - new commercial products
% OB - obituaries
% PA - computer program abstracts
% RI - reference information
% SG - structural genomics papers
% SI - short format inorganic compounds
% SM - short format metal-organic compounds
% SO - short format organic compounds
% SP - short structural papers
% SR - software reviews
% TE - teaching and education
\paperlang{english} % Can be english, french, german or russian
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Information about journal to which submitted
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\journalcode{J} % Indicate the journal to which submitted
% A - Acta Crystallographica Section A
% B - Acta Crystallographica Section B
% C - Acta Crystallographica Section C
% D - Acta Crystallographica Section D
% E - Acta Crystallographica Section E
% J - Journal of Applied Crystallography
% S - Journal of Synchrotron Radiation
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% The following entries will be changed as required by editorial staff
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\journalyr{2003}
\journaliss{1}
\journalvol{59}
\journalfirstpage{000}
\journallastpage{000}
\journalreceived{0 XXXXXXX 0000}
\journalaccepted{0 XXXXXXX 0000}
\journalonline{0 XXXXXXX 0000}


% \let\proof\relax
% \let\endproof\relax
% \usepackage{amsthm}



\begin{document} 

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The introductory (header) part of the paper
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The title of the paper. Use \shorttitle to indicate an abbreviated title
% for use in running heads (you will need to uncomment it).
\title{Title of Paper}
%\shorttitle{Short Title}
% Authors’ names and addresses. Use \cauthor for the main (contact) author.
% Use \author for all other authors. Use \aff for authors’ affiliations.
% Use lower-case letters in square brackets to link authors to their
% affiliations; if there is only one affiliation address, remove the [a].
\cauthor[a]{Forename}{Surname}{email}{address if different from \aff}
\author[b]{Forename}{Surname}
\aff[a]{First affiliation address \country{England}}
\aff[b]{Second affiliation address}
% Use \shortauthor to indicate an abbreviated author list for use in
% running heads (you will need to uncomment it).
%\shortauthor{Soape, Author and Doe}
% Use \vita if required to give biographical details (for authors of
% invited review papers only). Uncomment it.
%\vita{Author’s biography}
% Keywords (required for Journal of Synchrotron Radiation only)
% Use the \keyword macro for each word or phrase, e.g.
% \keyword{X-ray diffraction}\keyword{muscle}
%\keyword{keyword}
% PDB and NDB reference codes for structures referenced in the article and
% deposited with the Protein Data Bank and Nucleic Acids Database (Acta
% Crystallographica Section D). Repeat for each separate structure e.g
% \PDBref[dethiobiotin synthetase]{1byi} \NDBref[d(G$_4$CGC$_4$)]{ad0002}
%\PDBref[optional name]{refcode}
%\NDBref[optional name]{refcode}
\maketitle % DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE
\begin{synopsis}
Supply a synopsis of the paper for inclusion in the Table of Contents.
\end{synopsis}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The main body of the paper
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Now enter the text of the document in multiple \section’s, \subsection’s
% and \subsubsection’s as required.
\section{Section title}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text.
\subsection{Title}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text.

\subsubsection{Title}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text.
% Appendices appear after the main body of the text. They are prefixed by
% a single \appendix declaration, and are then structured just like the
% body text.
\appendix
\section{Appendix title}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text.
\subsection{Title}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text.
\subsubsection{Title}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text.
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% The back matter of the paper - acknowledgements and references
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Acknowledgements come after the appendices
\ack{Acknowledgements}
% References are at the end of the document, between \begin{references}
% and \end{references} tags. Each reference is in a \reference entry.

\begin{references}
\reference{Author, A. \& Author, B. (1984). \emph{Journal} \textbf{Vol},
first page--last page.}
\end{references}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TABLES AND FIGURES SHOULD BE INSERTED AFTER THE MAIN BODY OF THE TEXT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Simple tables should use the tabular environment according to this
% model
\begin{table}
\caption{Caption to table}
\begin{tabular}{llcr} % Alignment for each cell: l=left, c=center, r=right
HEADING & FOR & EACH & COLUMN \\
\hline
entry & entry & entry & entry \\
entry & entry & entry & entry \\
entry & entry & entry & entry \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
% Postscript figures can be included with multiple figure blocks
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption describing figure.}
\includegraphics{main_gui.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: The error `Missing \begin{document}` is reported here because something is actually typeset before the real start of the document code and text.  That, as noted in both answers, is the activation of `\RHUBARB`.  As noted in the answers, it's unclear why that's done, but it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The full message is

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7364   \RHUBARB
                 % % hack - see above
```

The offending line is preceded by a comment which translates as "we know this is wrong"...

```
% The next line is rather mysterious. For some reason the way in which \_ is
% set up requires that it be instantiated in some hidden way like this:
% undoubtedly a subtle bug, but this provides a workaround for current
% dictionaries
\gdef\RHUBARB{\smash{$\phantom{\_}$}}%
  \RHUBARB% % hack - see above
```

If you delete or comment out the line

```
\RHUBARB% % hack - see above
```

Then it runs without error.

Comment: it works, thank you, would you please provide some explanation as well?

Comment: @cswah honestly I could not even guess what the class authors thought this did, it is typesetting a box the width of a `_` inside the class file before `\begin{document}`. I suggested deleting it, If I could guess the intention I would have suggested what to do instead but it just does nothing remotely useful so all I could suggest is deleting it.

Comment: Well, that cures the error message, but…

Comment: @egreg you know the problem it was trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle They're doing a big mess when typesetting the first section, instead of just asking to `\maketitle`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error are the strange lines

```
\gdef\RHUBARB{\smash{$\phantom{\_}$}}%
  \RHUBARB% % hack - see above
```

but I can say why it used not to raise errors. In 2018 some LaTeX kernel commands were modified to ensure they’re always processed in LR-mode (horizontal mode, in TeXspeak): among them `\smash`.

Previously, `\smash` just contributed an `\hbox` to the main vertical list, so it didn't trigger the `Missing \begin{document}` error.

On the other hand, removing `\RHUBARB` does not really fix things: running your document with TeX Live 2017 yields

[image]

Commenting out the `\RHUBARB` line and running with TeX Live 2021 yields

[image]

which I’d say cannot be considered good output.

We can notice one other aspect besides the obviously wrong section title: some vertical space is missing after the first rule. The surprising typesetting of “Appendix A” can be cured by adding a blank line before `\appendix` in the source: it is due to the class using `\vspace\baselineskip` instead of `\vskip\baselineskip` or, even better, `\par\vspace{\baselineskip}`.

You can get the space back by changing

```
\gdef\RHUBARB{\smash{$\phantom{\_}$}}%
  \RHUBARB% % hack - see above
```

into

```
\gdef\RHUBARB{\hbox{\smash{$\phantom{\_}$}}}%
  \RHUBARB% % hack - see above
```

so the mysterious hack works the same as before.

The wrong typesetting of the section title is cured by commenting out line 1326 in `iucr.cls`

```
    \thesection.\ #1\par%
    %\vskip-\baselineskip%
    \vskip4pt minus 4pt}%
```

Now the output is as expected

[image]

Comment: the \RUBARB "hack" isn't actually doing anything is it though, isn't it just the same as using `\hbox{}` at that point and adding a an empty box, why the  phantom `\_` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No idea of how it popped in their minds…

Comment: If they'd instead used `\AtBeginDocument{\RHUBARB}` that error wouldn't have happened.  Maybe others, but not that one.